# MongoDB Text Search find similar words

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoose-populate

we have a database with names of wines and beer(s). We're using MongoDB and our document structure for each wine or beer company looks like this:

```
{
    name: String //this is the company name
    products: [
       {
        name: String //this is the product's name
        ...
       }
    ],
    ...
}
```

I have created a text index on both the company name and product name, the text search is working fine but it's not working as expected. For example we'd like our app to be able to return results when someone searches for a product named ***Bellissima*** and the text they send is ***Belisima*** OR ***Bellisima*** or any variations of that word.

Is that even possible with MongoDB's text search? How can I make it smarter? I'm not a MongoDB expert but I know it has something to do with word stemming or something so is there a way I can modify that?? Or any other workaround to give the user most appropriate results? Because searching for Belisima doesn't return any results because that's not the exact word saved in database.

Comment: there's a readymade [solution](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/wiki/11.-Fuzzy-Text-Search) for c# but don't know about mongoose. you could however implement it yourself with mongoose. the linked page describes how it's done.